# wamp server red icon & could not execute menu item

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I know this is not the first time this error has been reported, but I still can't solve it!

**Settings**

- Windows 7 64 bit
- wamp server 2.4
- php 5.4.12
- apache 2.4.4

**error**

1. localhost, localhost/phpmyadmin not found by browser
2. red wamp icon
3. "put online/offline" gives the error: could not execute menu item (internal error)...

**solutions that didn't work**

1. Uninstalling skype (which wasn't running in the first place, but just in case)
2. httpd.conf port 80 to 8080
3. adding wamp to firewall exceptions
4. re-installing wamp

Please help, thank you.

edit:
I couldn't wait any longer so I had to try this desperate "solution"...
So I downloaded and installed an earlier version of wampserver: http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.3) 2.2E
and everything is working fine!

Comment: after changing the port 80 to 8080 did you tired
http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Yes I did, not found =(

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that your W7 system has not have all the required versions of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.

```
The 2008 Redist (32bit) is used by wampmanager even if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer.
The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
```

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Link1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Link2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required [Link3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMP 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Link4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

> > Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as wampmanager uses this <<

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)  [Link5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)  [Link6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 [Link7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x64.exe

Comment: thank you, but I downloaded and installed links 4 through 7, restarted all services > no good... exited and re-launched wamp > no good

Answer (score 0):

FOR WAMP 64bit
Microsoft Visual

> C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) [http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582]
> **Yes
>   you need the x86 Package regardless**
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
>   Redistributable Package (x64) [http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15336]
> Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) [http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523]
> If
>   you are using WampServer 2.4
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 [http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679]
> And
>   select
>   vcredist_x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem is that the port Apache is trying to use is actually being used by some other application. Either
1. Change the port no. from the file http.conf or httpd.conf from 80 to smething else
             Listen 8080
    change 8080 to something else.

1. check out which application is using the port and shut it down. Check the port status using "cports" aplication or any other that you prefer. Then it will work just fine.